# Origin of Chhath Puja

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, draupadi, chhath

This [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chhath#cite_note-42) mentions that Draupadi and Kunti performed the Chhath Puja. However, the same page also mentions it to be a folk festival, which is celebrated on the Shukla Shashti of Kartika Masa (i.e. 6 days after Diwali). I want to know if there are any mentions of this festival in Mahabharata and our Puranas or if is it just a folk festival.

[image]

Comment: I know it is performed in Bihar. Wondering whether it is a festival of the Saura sect of Hindus.

Comment: The origin is puranic (carried from memory), not sure if any mahapuranas or any minor puranas do cover it.

Answer (score 1):

14th century *Maithilī paṇḍita Rudradhara* mentions the *Vivasvat-ṣaṣṭhī vrata* (popularly known as *Chat-Pūjā*) in his
*Smṛti* compendium called *Varṣakṛtya*.

He states that in this *vrata*, the votary is to observe restraint on *Kārtika śuklā pañcamī*, observe fast on the next day accompanied by offering *arghya* to *Sūrya* during sunset in the banks of a waterbody after worshipping Him with fruits, flowers, scents, lamps, incense & foodstuff accompanied by music & dance, keep awake that night through music & dance, then on the next day, again offer *arghya* to *Sūrya* during sunrise & observe His special worship & fast thoughtout the day, & finally terminate the fast on *Kārtika śuklā aṣṭamī* accompanied by feeding of *brāhmaṇa*s & hearing of the *vratakathā*.

*Chat-Pūjā* is also mentioned as *Pratihāra ṣaṣṭhī* by 15th century *Maithilī paṇḍita Vidyāpati* in his *Smṛti* compendium (also named) *Varṣakṛtya*. However, it wasn't possible to procure a copy of it.

The *vrata-katha* mentioned by *Rudradhara* (purportedly from the *Skandapurāṇa*) is extremely simple at the best. A person is born wretched & afflicted with leprosy, so he approaches a *brāhmaṇa* for remedy. The *brāhmaṇa* advises performance of *Vivasvat-ṣaṣṭhī vrata*, the person observes it & gets rid of his leprosy & misfortune. Another poor *brāhmaṇa* hears about this *vrata* & becomes rich after observing it. And thus the *vrata* gets popular among the masses.